# Byte range requests in Django REST + nginx (dokku)

Tags: django, nginx, video-streaming

In my Django application, I have a `Video` model with a `file` FileField that represents a user-uploaded video.

I serve these files via a Django REST API view that looks like this:

```
class VideoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Video.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VideoSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        file = instance.file
        response = FileResponse(
            file,
            as_attachment=True,
        )
        response["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename="video.mp4"'
        response["Accept-Ranges"] = "bytes"
        return response
```

the frontend accesses the video like this:

```
<video playsinline controls>
        <source type="video/webm" :src="videoUrl"/>
        <p>
           Videos are unsupported in your browser
        </p>
</video>
```

The application is deployed using dokku, which has gunicorn and nginx sit in front of Django.

The problem is: in production, when the video player is opened, I am unable to seek. The video just proceeds from timestamp 00:00 all the way to the end, even if I drag the video timeline thumb to other positions.

I learned that has to do with byte range requests, and not supporting them is the cause of not being able to seek while the video is playing.

Adding  `response["Accept-Ranges"] = "bytes"` in my viewset makes it work locally, but when I push to production the problem is still there.

What can I do to solve this? I tried [DjangoRangeMiddleware](https://pypi.org/project/DjangoRangeMiddleware/) but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: are you using Nginx to serve the static files instead of Django? Nginx doesn't know about your Django view and its ability to handle range requests, so it just serves the whole file.